# Convert CURL XML response into Array in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I am trying to convert a XML response via CURL to an array in PHP. I have tried with the below code but not getting expected result array.

With using simplexml_load_string:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
print_r($arr);//giving array () empty
```

With using SimpleXMLElement:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
print_r($xml); //giving  SimpleXMLElement Object ( )  empty array
```

My Curl response :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
  <soap:Header>
    <OGHeader transactionID="00239870" timeStamp="2009-02-23T01:55:01.4625+05:30" primaryLangID="E" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Core/">
      <Origin entityID="WEST" systemType="ORS" />
      <Destination entityID="OWS" systemType="WEB" />
    </OGHeader>
    <wsa:Action>http://webservices</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:a9a70c23-3d94-4640-9aac-8ac63694733a</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:eb565d90-b682-45e9-b18d-c03fa7323019</wsa:RelatesTo>
    <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateBookingResponse xmlns:r="http://webservices" xmlns:hc="http://webservices/" xmlns:c="http://webservices" xmlns="http://webservices">
      <Result resultStatusFlag="FAIL">
        <c:Text>
          <c:TextElement></c:TextElement>
        </c:Text>
        <c:OperaErrorCode>PRIOR_STAY</c:OperaErrorCode>
      </Result>
    </CreateBookingResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
var_dump($xml->asXML());
```

Your xml is there as you can see.

Simplexml implements ArrayIterator, therefore you can iterate using `foreach` or use any of the simpleXmlElement methods to navigate through it (such as `children()` or `xpath()`).

Comment: this is printing : `<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;&#10;&lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/&quot; xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xmlns:xsd=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema&quot; xmlns:wsa=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing&quot;&gt;&lt;soap...entityID=&quot;OWS&quot; systemType=&quot;W'...</font> <i>(length=1322)</i>
</pre>`